# Load different env variables with .env and create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I need to load for each development/production server a different .env file.

```
Dev/Prod Server     | .env file
---------------------------------------------
localhost           | .env.development.local
development         | .env.development
qa                  | .env.qa
production          | .env.production
```

So, I tried to edit the package.json in this way

```
"start-js": "react-scripts start .env.development.local",
"start": " npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
"build:dev": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build .env.development",
"build:qa": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build .env.qa",
"build:pro": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build .env.production"
```

but if I execute a `build:*` command, the file loaded is always .env.production because the NODE_ENV is production. Is it possibile to load the others .env file with `"build:*` command?

Comment: try to look at dotenv. you can load different env files using it

Comment: @ReiDien What should be the script for `build:qa` with dotenv? `npm run build-css && react-scripts dotenv_config_path=qa.env`  don't recognize `dotenv_config_path`

Answer (score 2):

I solved my question using react-app-env and renaming the .env file.

```
Dev/Prod Server     | .env file
---------------------------------------------
qa                  | qa.env
```

And the `build:qa` scripts, for example, became:

```
"build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
"build:qa": "react-app-env --env-file=qa.env build"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [switchenv](https://github.com/christiaanwesterbeek/switchenv). It's a command line tool for quickly switching .env file from Keepass entries (content from the Notes field)

Simply running `yarn switchenv development` would replace your `.env` file.

Run `yarn switchenv production` and replace your `.env` file with the production one.

Basically, all your .env files are stored as entries in a Keepass file. The content of the .env file for each entry should be stored in the Note field. Using `switchenv` reads that Keepass file and replaces the `.env` file with the Notes of the entry.